# what would be the scope of a broadcasted and repartitioned dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, join, broadcast

If I have a spark dataframe(rightdf) ~4gb, can be used this part of code in a join:
leftdf.join(broadcast(rightdf.repartition(2)))?

Comment: Hello, Adrian. Please, check the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section. So you could draw more attention with more detailed question, code you already tried and more.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to repartition `rightdf` before broadcast it. In fact, when you're using a broadcast join, the whole broadcast dataframe (in your case it's `rightdf`) while be sending to each node in the cluster.

So calling `repartition` before `broadcast` while only decrease your performance.

Comment: what about repartition(1)?